# Cannot get past a "SparkException: Job aborted" error when attempting to use a custom UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, geolocation, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using Jupyter notebook on a Google Dataproc Cluster to do some analysis of Uber pickup data in NYC and keep running into problems trying to use a UDF to map lat/lon coordinates to a neighborhood name. My PySpark dataframe has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Lat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- Lon: float (nullable = true)
 |-- Base: string (nullable = true)
```

And it looks like this:

```
+-------------------+-------+--------+------+
|                 dt|    Lat|     Lon|  Base|
+-------------------+-------+--------+------+
|2014-04-01 00:11:00| 40.769|-73.9549|B02512|
|2014-04-01 00:17:00|40.7267|-74.0345|B02512|
|2014-04-01 00:21:00|40.7316|-73.9873|B02512|
|2014-04-01 00:28:00|40.7588|-73.9776|B02512|
|2014-04-01 00:33:00|40.7594|-73.9722|B02512|
+-------------------+-------+--------+------+
```

What I'm trying to do is use the `Lat` and `Lon` coordinates, compare them to a geojson shapefile of NYC neighborhoods, and get the neighborhood that a particular coordinate belongs to so I can add that info as a column. What I want at the end is:

```
+-------------------+-------+--------+------+----------------+
|                 dt|    Lat|     Lon|  Base|             Loc|
+-------------------+-------+--------+------+----------------+
|2014-04-01 00:11:00| 40.769|-73.9549|B02512|        Flushing|
|2014-04-01 00:17:00|40.7267|-74.0345|B02512| Upper East Side|
|2014-04-01 00:21:00|40.7316|-73.9873|B02512| Lower East Side|
|2014-04-01 00:28:00|40.7588|-73.9776|B02512|         Bayside|
|2014-04-01 00:33:00|40.7594|-73.9722|B02512|    Williamsburg|
+-------------------+-------+--------+------+----------------+
```

I have the following function defined:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def add_neighborhood(lon, lat):
    for i in geofile['features']:
        p = path.Path(i['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
        if p.contains_point((lon, lat)):
            return i['properties']['neighborhood']

add_neighborhood_udf = udf(add_neighborhood, StringType())
```

But when I actually go to use it:

```
df2 = df2.withColumn('Loc', add_neighborhood_udf(df['Lon'], df['Lat']))
df2.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o227.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 21.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 21.0 (TID 188, spark-cluster-w-1.c.airy-environs-194607.internal, executor 6): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 164, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 93, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
```

What I have been able to diagnose so far is this:

1. I can get a simple custom UDF to work that returns only the longitude as a new column, or longitude+1 or some simple math like that.
2. I can also get this entire problem solved in Pandas. But I have a few hundred millions of rows so ideally, I can use PySpark for this.
3. When I try to combine the lon/lat in an array or tuple, I instead get something like `[Ljava.lang.Objec...]` returned.
4. So I think the problem lies either with the `[Ljava.lang.Objec...]` object or PySpark's ability to access matplotlib in the UDF.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Thanks.

#### Edit:

Going one step at a time, I've discovered the the error happens when I make the call to matplotlib's path to draw a polygon from a set of coordinates.

```
p = path.Path(i['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
```

Why would this line alone raise that error when I'm not even returning the value `p` in my UDF function?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but what happens if the neighborhood is not found? Your function doesn't have a default return value. Maybe try adding `return 'Not Found'` at the end of the udf? As currently written, it will return `None` and perhaps that is a problem because the `udf` is defined to return a `StringType()`.

Comment: Actually, that's *probably* not your issue (I just tested it).

Comment: Good point! While it doesn't solve the issue, I did edit the code so it'll return `0` if it does not find a match.

Comment: What does `print i['geometry']['coordinates'][0]` before`p = path.Path(i['geometry']['coordinates'][0])` print? Is the geojson somewhere accessible to all nodes, e.g. an ftp?Where is `geofile` declared? If not within the udf then you need to use a `broadcast` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! After further troubleshooting, I think the issue is that my workers do not have matplotlib/numpy/etc. so they fail at the following line in my udf which relies on matplotlib: `p = path.Path(i['geometry']['coordinates'][0])`. I'll go research how I can install those dependencies on my workers.